# How do I calculate binomial coefficient with memoization?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, memoization, binomial-coefficients

The recursive form is like that:

```
co:: (Int,Int) -> Int
co| k == 0 || k == n = 1
  | 0 < k, k < n = co(n-1,k-1) + co(n-1,k)
  | otherwise = 0
```

How do I memorize so I don't have to make the same calculations that often?

Comment: Let's start by getting a solution that compiles and provides correct answers. You need to declare `n` and `k`.

Comment: After you fix that, I think a more efficient solution comes directly from the definition: `nCk = n!/((k!)(n-k!))`. You can use `product` to calculate the factorials and then there is less need for memoization.

Comment: You would store the values in a boxed data structure such as a map or array. Either update and insert each new value into the map, passing the updated map as program state, or use laziness to create a structure full of thunks, which will calculate the value once, only if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s how to implement binomial coefficients if you are feeling sane and want someone to understand your program:

```
--| computes the binomial coefficient n choose k = n!/k!(n-k)!
binom n k = product [max (k+1) (n-k+1) .. n] `div` product [1 .. min k (n-k)]
```

Here is a simple way to memoize a function of two arguments like this:

```
binom n k = (vals !! n) !! k where
  vals = 1 : [ 1 : [if k == n
                    then 1
                    else binom (n-1) (k-1) + binom (n-1) k
                   | k <- [1..n]]
             | n <- [1..]]
```